# Добавление элементов в список

Tags: c++builder, c++

Добрый вечер господа, вобщем написал я тут список, вот такой:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct link  
{
  int data;   
  link* next; 
} ;

class linklist // список
{
  private:
    link* first;
  public:
    linklist ( )           
      { first = NULL; }    
    void additem ( int d ); 
    void display ( );

};

void linklist::additem ( int d ) 
{
  link* newlink = new link;      
  newlink->data = d;           
  newlink->next = first;         
  first = newlink;              
}

void linklist::display ( )
{
  link* current = first;           
  while( current )                
  {
    cout << current->data << endl; 
    current = current->next;      
  }
}

int main ( )
{   int el,n,k;
  linklist li;       
  cout<<"input number of element";
  cin>>n;

  while (n>0)
  {
     cout<<"input current element";
     cin>>el;
     li.additem ( el ); 
     n--;
  }

  li.display ( );
   getch();
  return 0;
}
```

вобщем программа умеет вводить небходимое количество элементов, + функция отображения
не знаю как вставить какой-нибудь элемент в список, в начало вставить легко, и в конец тоже, а вот в определенную позицию понятия не имею как, + при вставке другие элементы смещаются.
И еще вывести элемент по его индексу не знаю как.....Самое главное со вставкой бы разобраться)
помогите кто а то сдавать на зачет уже пора.

Comment: @Илья Бобрышев, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @Илья Бобышев, конечно, скорее всего Вам нужно написать свою программу (в учебных целях), но при желании можете ознакомиться с [реализацией списков в Linux](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/).

Comment: спасибо за материал.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/sitev/cjCore/blob/master/src/object.cpp

Здесь поищи реализацию класса List, вдруг подойдёт...

Comment: А Вы на дату вопроса посмотрели? Подозреваю, что почти за 3 года автор (кстати, так более и ни разу нас не посетивший) полностью  утратил интерес к этой теме.

Comment: да уж, бывает )

Answer (score 0):

Заводите метод, в котором  в цикле будете перебирать элементы списка один за другим, по мере перехода к следующему элементу увеличиваете какую-нибудь целочисленную переменную, в которой будете хранить номер текущего элемента. Когда эта переменная станет равна требуемому индексу, меняете указатель next текущего элемента на вставляемый, а next  вставляемого элемента - на тот, на который до этого указывал текущий. Заканчиваете цикл. Вот как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

```
void linklist::insert(int pos, int value)
{
  link* pCurrent = first;
  int nIndex = 0;
  while(nIndex<pos)
  {
    if(!pCurrent)
    {
       //Всё плохо, количество элементов меньше чем нужно
       //Можно бросить что-нибудь или выйти как-то иначе
       //throw smthg();
    }
    pCurrent = pCurrent->next;
    ++nIndex;
  }

  link* pNewItem = new link;
  pNewItem->next = pCurrent->next;
  pNewItem->data = value;
  pCurrent->next = pNewItem;
}
```

Ещё вам срочно необходим деструктор! Вы не удаляете свой список после использования.

Comment: Ещё я бы хотел заметить что ваша реализация конечно может быть любой, но в моей практике в большинстве случаев удобнее хранить указатель на последний элемент (чтобы вставлять в конец, а не в начало, как в приведённом коде). Плюс удобно иметь счётчик количества элементов в списке. Ну это уже придирки.

Comment: спасибо за дельный совет)

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то в началах писал такое. Может пригодится. ps. Деструктор-таки придется писать самому. И еще лишние штуки есть. Разберетесь, я думаю, что Вам нужно.

```
template <typename valueType> class List
{
//  конструктор
    List(valueType Value = 0, List *Next = NULL)
    {
        this->Value = Value;
        this->Next = Next;
    }

    void Clone(List *to)
    {

    }

//  Возврат длины списка
    unsigned int GetLength()
    {
        unsigned int i = 1;
        List *tmp = this;

        while(tmp->Next)
        {
            tmp = tmp->Next;
            ++i;
        }

        return i;
    }

//  Возврат значения по номеру
    valueType GetValue(unsigned int index)
    {
        if(!index)
            return this->Value;

        List *tmp = this;

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
            tmp = tmp->Next;

        return tmp->Value;
    }

//  Вставка значения в начало списка
    void Put(valueType Value)
    {
        List *newValue = new List(this->Value, this->Next);

        this->Value = Value;
        this->Next = newValue;
    }

//  Вставка узла в начало списка
    List *Put(List *node)
    {
        node->Next = this;
        return node;
    }

//  Вставка значения по индексу 
    void Insert(valueType Value, unsigned int index)
    {
        List *newValue = new List(Value);

        if(!index)
        {
            newValue->Value = this->Value;
            newValue->Next = this->Next;

            this->Value = Value;
            this->Next = newValue;

            return;
        }

        List *tmp = this;
        --index;

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
            tmp = tmp->Next;

        newValue->Next = tmp->Next;
        tmp->Next = newValue;
    }

//  Вставка значения в конец списка
    void Append(valueType Value)
    {
        List *newValue = new List(Value);
        List *tmp = this;

        while(tmp->Next) 
            tmp = tmp->Next;

        tmp->Next = newValue;
    }

//  Удаление из списка по номеру
    void Delete(unsigned int index)
    {
        List *tmp = this;

        if(!index)
        {
            tmp = this->Next;

            this->Value = this->Next->Value;
            this->Next = this->Next->Next;

            delete tmp;

            return;
        }

        List *tmpDeleted;

        for(int i = 0; i < index - 1; ++i)
            tmp = tmp->Next;

        tmpDeleted = tmp->Next;
        tmp->Next = tmp->Next->Next;

        delete tmpDeleted;
    }

//  перестановка элементов 
    List *Move(int from, int to)
    {
        List *newHead = this, *tmp = this, *tmpMoved, *tmpHead;
        int i = 0;

        //  Вырезать элемент, который надо переместить
        if(from)    
        {
            for(--from; i < from; ++i)
                tmp = tmp->Next;

            tmpMoved = tmp->Next;
            tmp->Next = tmp->Next->Next;

            // Чтобы лишний раз не перемещаться по списку
            if(from > to - 1)
            {
                tmp = newHead;
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        else    //  Если надо переместить голову
        {
            tmpMoved = tmp;
            newHead = newHead->Next;
        }

        //  Если надо переместить в начало
        if(!to)
        {
            tmpHead = newHead;
            newHead = tmpMoved;
            newHead->Next = tmpHead;

            return newHead;
        }

        //  Переместить на нужную позицию
        for(--to; i < to; ++i)
            tmp = tmp->Next;

        tmpHead = tmp->Next;
        tmp->Next = tmpMoved;
        tmp->Next->Next = tmpHead;

        return newHead;     
    }

//  Поиск элемента в массиве возврат индекса, если нет вхождений возврат -1
    int FindValue(valueType Value, unsigned int from = 0)
    {
        List *tmp = this;
        int i = 0;

        for(; i < from; ++i)
            tmp = tmp->Next;

        for(; tmp; tmp = tmp->Next)
        {
            if(Value == tmp->Value)
                return i;

            ++i;

        }

        return -1;
    }

//  Поиск максимального элемента, возврат адреса
    List *FindMax(List **beforeMax = NULL)
    {
        List *maxNode = this;
        List *tmp = this->Next;
        List *beforeTmp = this;

        for(; tmp; tmp = tmp->Next)
        {
            if(maxNode->Value < tmp->Value)
            {
                *beforeMax = beforeTmp;
                maxNode = tmp;
            }

            beforeTmp = beforeTmp->Next;
        }

        if(maxNode == this)
            *beforeMax = NULL;

        return maxNode;
    }

//  Поиск максимального элемента, возврат индекса
    unsigned int FindMax(unsigned int from = 0)
    {
        valueType maxValue = this->Value;
        List *tmp = this->Next;

        unsigned int maxIndex = from, i = 1;

        if(from)
        {
            for(; i < from; ++i)
                tmp = tmp->Next;

            maxValue = tmp->Value;
        }

        for(; tmp; tmp = tmp->Next)
        {
            if(maxValue < tmp->Value)
            {
                maxValue = tmp->Value;
                maxIndex = i;
            }

            ++i;
        }

        return maxIndex;
    }

//  Поиск минимального элемента, возврат индекса
    unsigned int FindMin(unsigned int from = 0)
    {
        valueType minValue = this->Value;
        List *tmp = this->Next;

        unsigned int minIndex = from, i = 1;

        if(from)
        {
            for(; i < from; ++i)
                tmp = tmp->Next;

            minValue = tmp->Value;

        }

        for(; tmp; tmp = tmp->Next)
        {
            if(minValue > tmp->Value)
            {
                minValue = tmp->Value;
                minIndex = i;
            }

            ++i;
        }

        return minIndex;
    }

//  Сортировка по возрастанию
    List *SortByAsc()
    {
        List *tmp = this;
        List *max;
        List *maxPrev;
        List *newHead;

        max = tmp->FindMax(&maxPrev);

        if(maxPrev)
            maxPrev->Next = max->Next;
        else
            tmp = tmp->Next;

        max->Next = NULL;
        newHead = max;

        while(tmp)
        {
            max = tmp->FindMax(&maxPrev);

            if(maxPrev)
                maxPrev->Next = max->Next;
            else
                tmp = tmp->Next;

            newHead = newHead->Put(max);
        }

        return newHead;
    }

//  Сортировка по убыванию
    List *SortByDesc()
    {
        List *newHead = this;
        unsigned int min = newHead->FindMin();
        unsigned int i = 1, length = this->GetLength();

        if(min)
            newHead = newHead->Move(min, 0);

        while(i < length)
        {
            min = newHead->FindMin(i);

            newHead = newHead->Move(min, 0);

            ++i;
        }

        return newHead;
    }

//  Построчный вывод значений элементов массива
    void  ShowList()
    {
        List *tmp = this;

        for(unsigned int i = 0; tmp; tmp = tmp->Next, ++i)
            cout << "Value[" << i << "] = " << tmp->Value << endl;
    }

    valueType Value;
    List *Next;
};
```

Comment: вот это полезная сборка, пригодится)